# Unix Shell - Parsing file value into a variable

Tags: shell, parsing, unix, awk, grep

How can I assign a string to a variable like below:

Input content:

```
+++    USCDB        2016-07-29 20:19:53 PGW    #036326 %%/*HWHandle=12547*/LST EPS:IMSI="515020211157018";%% RETCODE = 0 SUCCESS0001:Operation is successful

                          IMSI = 515020211157018
                          ISDN = 632000000016
                           EPS = NOTPROV
                        ANCHOR = FALSE
                        ICSIND = FALSE

Total count = 5

There is together 1 report

---    END
+++    USCDB        2016-07-29 20:19:53 PGW    #036331 %%/*HWHandle=12547*/LST EPS:IMSI="515020211157020";%% RETCODE = 0
SUCCESS0001:Operation is successful

                          IMSI = 515020211157020
                          ISDN = 632000000018
                           EPS = PROV
                     AMBRMAXUL = 7104000
                     AMBRMAXDL = 15200000
               RATFREQSELPRIID = 256
                        ANCHOR = FALSE
                        ICSIND = FALSE
                           MPS = FALSE
                      TAUTIMER = 0
                           MDT = NOTGIVEN
                   LTEAUTOPROV = FALSE
                    RELAY_NODE = FALSE
                     EPSODBPOS = NOBPOS
                  LTE_M2M_FLAG = FALSE

Total count = 15

There is together 1 report
```

While I'm currently using grep and awk to get the value above.

```
IMSI=$(echo $LINE | grep 'IMSI' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')  
ISDN=$(echo $LINE | grep 'ISDN' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')  
EPS=$(echo $LINE | grep 'EPS =' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}') 

AMBRMAXUL=$(echo $LINE | grep 'AMBRMAXUL' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}') 

AMBRMAXDL=$(echo $LINE | grep 'AMBRMAXDL' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
```

But when printing all IMSI value will be stored in one variable

Expected output:

```
515020211157018 632000000016 NOTPROV  
515020211157020 632000000018 PROV 7104000 15200000
```

Comment: Does the variable contain spaces for example is `AMB RMAXUL` allowed?

Comment: @shellter : You might have broken the format for expected output

Comment: hm... all I did was use the `{}` tool. If you think it is wrong, feel free to amend. Good luck to all.

Comment: Don't pipe `grep` to `awk`.  `echo $LINE | grep 'IMSI' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'` is better written `echo $LINE | awk -F= '/IMSI/{print $2}'`

Comment: Is the `END` tag on the second report really missing in your input?

Comment: @RobertJayLumayag: Per sjsam's comment, did I break your sample output, should it be 2 or 3 lines? If 3 lines, where does the break go? I'll fix it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the record contains `AMBRMAXUL` & `AMBRMAXDL` only when `EPS = PROV`, below should solve the problem:

```
awk '/^[[:blank:]]*IMSI[[:blank:]]+|^[[:blank:]]*ISDN[[:blank:]]+/{printf "%s ",$3}
      /^[[:blank:]]*EPS[[:blank:]]+/{if($3 == "PROV"){printf "%s",$3}else{print $3};check=0}
      /^[[:blank:]]*AMBRMAXUL[[:blank:]]+|^[[:blank:]]*AMBRMAXDL[[:blank:]]+/{check++;val=val" "$3}
       check == 2 {print val;val="";check=0}' file
```

will give you

```
515020211157018 632000000016 NOTPROV
515020211157020 632000000018 PROV 7104000 15200000
```

which is what you're looking for.

I have used `print` which lets me work around hard-coding `\n` (less portable) to the script.

Comment: So just to be explicit, `awk '...' file | while read imsi isdn eps; do ... : things with "$imsi" and "$isdn" and "$eps"; done` whill allow you to loop over the values.  This should be easy to extend to add more values, and is way more efficient than repeatedly `echo`ing the entire file (which to top it off you were doing without quoting, but that's a separate issue) as well as more maintainable and readable.

Comment: Also notice how I converted your variables to lowercase; uppercase is reserved for system variables.

Comment: @tripleee : Noted your first point. but I don't have any variables outside the awk-script here.

Comment: I meant that for the OP primarily.  Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Thanks Sir! this will helps a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    case ${line%% *} in
        IMSI) IMSI=${line##* }
              ;;
        ISDN) ISDN=${line##* }
              ;;
        EPS) EPS=${line##* }
             ;;
        AMBRMAXUL) AMBRMAXUL=${line##* }
             ;;
        AMBRMAXDL) AMBRMAXDL=${line##* }
             ;;
        ---) echo $IMSI $ISDN $EPS $AMBRMAXUL $AMBRMAXDL
             unset IMSI ISDN EPS AMBRMAXUL AMBRMAXDL
             ;;
    esac
done < test.in
```

Let's test:

```
$ bash test.sh
515020211157018 632000000016 NOTPROV
515020211157020 632000000018 PROV 7104000 15200000
```

BTW, above expects every record to end with `---    END`, which seems to be the case with the first record but not the second.

Comment: Hi Sir,

Thanks for your advise, assuming I will use this code. Can you confirm if the code below is advisable to add condition for value of AMBRMAXUL and AMBRMAXDL.

>        AMBRMAXUL) AMBRMAXUL=${line##* }
>             ;;
>        AMBRMAXDL) AMBRMAXDL=${line##* }
>             ;;
>        ---) if [ $EPS = "PROV" ]; then
>                 echo $IMSI $ISDN $EPS $AMBRMAXUL $AMBRMAXDL
>             else 
>                echo $IMSI $ISDN $EPS
>             fi
>            ;;

Output:
>515020211172557 632000005500 PROV 7104000 15200000
>515020211172560 632000005503 NOTPROV

Comment: That's how I would've done it, had I thought that far.